# How to get distinct node on condition Cypher-Neo4j

Tags: cypher, neo4jphp, node-neo4j, neo4j

I am new to neo4j, I have the following situation[image]

As shown in the figure above I have an Node `Admin` and nodes `Folder1, Folder2,Folder3`and other group of nodes like `FileA,FileB,FileC,FileD`.

- The `Admin` node has an `:access` relationship with property `qty`
  for the `Folder1,Folder2 and Folder3`.
- Each Folder nodes have `:next` relationship with respective File
  nodes as represented in the above figure.

### Question :

How to write a Cypher query to return the **distinct** `FileA , FileB ,FileC,FileD` nodes from these folder nodes having maximum `qty` value?

I have tried,but I couldn't get it.

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What does high mean?

Try this:

```
MATCH (person:Person {name:"Admin"})-[r:access]->(folder)-[:next*]->(file)
WHERE r.qty > {high}
WITH file,r
ORDER r.qty DESC
RETURN distinct file
```

high is a parameter, e.g. `{high:5}`

Comment: high is not a paramter i mean which folder have a greater qty in the access relationship

Answer (score 0):

First, use http://console.neo4j.org/ for sharing test setups.

You want to use the [MAX](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-max) aggregator. The setup is a little weird because of how neo4j filtering works.

```
MATCH (n)-[r:access]->()
// Reduce all items to one row, and get max quantity
WITH COLLECT(r) as r,  MAX(r.qty) as maxvalue
// Unwind collected values, and cleanup variables with WITH
UNWIND r as r2 
WITH r2 as r, maxvalue
// Filter rows on max
WHERE r.qty=maxvalue
// Do stuff
return *
```

Or, if you have the luxery of APOC installed

```
MATCH (n)-[r:access]->()
// get max value
WITH r,  apoc.coll.max(COLLECT(r.qty)) as maxvalue
// Filter rows on max
WHERE r.qty=maxvalue
// Do stuff
return *
```